# SQL aggregate function inside an aggregate function

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I know it's not possible to nest aggregate functions. But I want to achieve something like this and quite confused about how to do this compromising performance.

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  count(CASE WHEN SUM(active_time) > 5 THEN user_id END) AS total_active_users, 
  count(CASE WHEN SUM(active_time) > 5 AND is_admin = true THEN user_id END) AS total_active_admin_users
FROM
(
  SELECT date, user_id, user_name, active_time, is_admin FROM users
)
GROUP BY date
```

It's really appreciated if someone could suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: please tag your dbms, add some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
select date, 
       sum(case when sum_active_time > 5 then 1 else 0 end) as  total_active_users, 
       sum(case when sum_active_time > 5 and is_admin then 1 else 0 end) as  total_active_admin_users
from (select u.*, sum(active_time) over (partition by user_id) as sum_active_time
      from users
     ) u
group by date;
```

However, I would expect `user_id` to be unique in a table called `users`.  That makes me wonder why you need to do a count or sum at all.  So, you might want:

```
select date, 
       sum(case when active_time > 5 then 1 else 0 end) as  total_active_users, 
       sum(case when active_time > 5 and is_admin then 1 else 0 end) as  total_active_admin_users
from users
group by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, 
       COUNT(user_id) as total_active_users,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN is_admin = 1 THEN user_id END ) as total_active_admin_users
FROM (
     SELECT  date, is_admin, user_id
     FROM users
     GROUP BY date, is_admin, user_id
     HAVING SUM(active_time) > 5
    ) t
GROUP BY date
```